# How to get inner text inside tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I retrieve the HTML inside an element, using jQuery?

For example, getting from this:

```
<html><body onload="someAction()"></body></html>
```

to this:

```
<body onload="someAction()"></body>
```

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: i need to get the inner thext inside a tag, the fult text including tags

Comment: you should add that comment to your qustion and maybe show where you use it/what you tried...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the html as a string that's within another element, use `.html()`.

```
$('html').html()
```

returns the string: `<body onload="someAction()"></body>`.

---

If your input code is already a string, such as:

```
var text = '<html><body onload="someAction()"></body></html>';
```

then you can parse and extract like this:

```
$(text).find('html').html();
```

returns the string: `<body onload="someAction()"></body>`.

Comment: im working with IE8 is it the same? thank you

Comment: Yes it is the same. jQuery will handle most browser quirks.

Comment: suppose i have :   var text = '<html><body onload="someAction()"></body></html>';   how do i get it?